# Systemd и python3

Tags: python, systemd

Стандартный конфиг сервиса:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "cd /root/EzBackUp && python3.8 EzBackUp.py"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Также пробовал:
`ExecStart=/root/EzBackUp/start.sh`, в котором написано:
`cd /root/EzBackUp && python3.8 EzBackUp.py`

Ошибки:

```
# sudo systemctl status backup.service
● backup.service - Backup
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/backup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-09-07 19:42:51 UTC; 9s ago
  Process: 19645 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c cd /root/EzBackUp && python3.8 EzBackUp.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 19645 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 07 19:42:51 *** systemd[1]: Started Backup.
Sep 07 19:42:51 *** systemd[19645]: backup.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /u
Sep 07 19:42:51 *** systemd[1]: backup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, s
Sep 07 19:42:51 *** systemd[1]: backup.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 07 19:42:51 *** systemd[1]: backup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Хотя при ручном запуске скрипта `/root/EzBackUp/start.sh` все работает исправно.
В чем ошибка?

Comment: Не знаю в чем ошибка, но лучше используйте WorkingDirectory, вместое того, что бы делать cd

Comment: И если вам нужны переменные окружения, то их желательно явно указывать в конфиге Environment="KEY=VALUE"

Comment: Указать полный путь до `python3.8`?

Comment: @MaximTimakov, алиасы не работают?

Comment: Указание `WorkingDirectory` и полный путь до `python3.8` помогли. Спасибо, @dhvcc @maxim-timakov